# Nextjs 13 /app/pricing/page.tsx directory can't use getServerSideProps for server side rendering

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I'm trying to use server side rendering in nextjs 13 with /app directory but I get this error

```js
./app\pricing\page.tsx
ReactServerComponentsError:

"getServerSideProps" is not supported in app/. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching
```

here are my code for /app/pricing/page.tsx

```js
'use client'
import axios from 'axios'
import { GetServerSideProps } from 'next'

export default function Pricing({ props }: any) {
  const { plans } = props
  return <div></div>
}

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {
  try {
    const res: any = await axios.get("/api/stripe/plans");
    return {
      props: {
        plans: res?.data?.plans
      }
    }
  }
  catch (error: any) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

Please help me to know how I can use server side rendering with nextjs 13 in /app directly without those errors

Here is what I want to achieve

Problem
Fetching subscription plans from database is taking long time that's why I want to use server side redenring to improve performance and avoid loading issues.

Comment: it is removed in app directory. you can still use it in pages directory. we can directly fetch data on server components now. before, we used the fetch the data in getServerSideProps which runs on the server and we were passing the returned value to the component as prop

Answer (score 0):

You could read from the documentation [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/get-server-side-props)

It can only be exported from the page component (pages folder).

[image]